# How do I share data between child directives in angular?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Lets say I have two directives parent-dir and child-dir

```
<div parent-dir>
  <div child-dir>
  <div child-dir>
</div>
<div parent-dir>
  <div child-dir>
  <div child-dir>
</div>
```

How do I share data between the first parent-dir directive and all of the child-dir directives within that element but isolated of the other parent-dir?

Comment: I'm not sure the scenario you are working with, but a solution could be angular services, a service is accessible from anywhere by injecting it. Anywhere in this case means parents, child and sibling directive.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are setting up your directives.  One way would be for the parent and child directives to create a new scope.  Children scope automatically inherit the parent's scope and can specifically access the parent's scope with `$parent`.  Siblings cannot [easily] access each others scope.  For in your example, `child-dir` can access their `parent-dir` but `parent-dir` cannot access another `parent-dir`

You can create a new scope using the following in the object you return when defining your directives

```
scope: {}
```

Note: if you use `scope: true`, you will create an isolated scope which has the parent scope of `rootScope` and not its logical parent.